# aws sqs error: "may not be available in the eu-central-1"

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, aws-sdk

After massive message treatment, sqs suddenly stops working then fire this error:

[image]
I don't understand, I'm 100% sure this service is available in this region and I got the right queues access.

How this could happen?

UPDATE 1:

when I restart the server, sqs will reconnect but will crash later again

Answer (score 0):

I did a quick Google and found a discussion in GIT hub about the AWS Javascript SDK. Apparently the discussion ended in the looking at the **networking layers / DNS** to see what goes wrong.

Meanwhile the suggestion was also to enable the **retryable** logic.

```
AWS.events.on('httpError', function() {
  if (this.response.error && this.response.error.code === 'UnknownEndpoint') {
    this.response.error.retryable = true;
  }
});
```

Detailed Discussion : https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/issues/528

Comment: I also found this discussion but it did not help, thank you anyway